# What is the solution of $\cosh(x)=(1-\epsilon) x \quad (\epsilon >0)$

Tags: numerical-methods, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

In a program of mine, I am solving numerically in the real domain (with limited precision) the equation
$$\cosh(x)=a\,x$$ which does not present any difficulty. The problem is that $a$ is a function of many other variables and I forgot to check, before solving, that $a >1$.

According to Murphy's law, in the middle of zillions of calculations, there was a crash. Recomputing $a$ with illimited precision, it was just a bit smaller than $1$.

So, out of pure curiosity, I started looking at the complex solutions of
$$\cosh(x)=(1-\epsilon)\,x \qquad \text{where} \qquad 0 <\epsilon <1$$ the numerical solutions of which being easily computed using Newton method using $x_0=1\pm i$. Making $\epsilon=10^{-k}$ I can obtain the solution with very high accuracy up to $k \sim 323\times 10^6$  (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FindRoot%5BCosh%5Bx%5D%3D%3D%281-10%5E%28-10%5E8%29%29x%2C%7Bx%2C1%2BI%7D%5D) for an example). $x_*$ noting the solution
$$\Re(x_*)=0.9760545183390074945207946979151719003359441073084578875553199$$
$$\Im(x_*)=\pm0.8709514657614091170725524453488181084144105977590102585922735$$ and none of these numbers is recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.

> So, my questions are
>
> - what are these numbers ?
> - is it possible to have the asymptotics of $x_*$ when $\epsilon \to 0^+$ ?

Comment: Curious. Looks like you are near a fixed point of $\cosh x$. I'm ignorant about those and the derivative has absolute value $>1$ around $z_0=0.976+0.871i$, so iteration fails to converge. Switching to $\operatorname{arcosh}(z)$.

Comment: Iterating $z_1=1+i$, $z_{n+1}=\operatorname{arcosh}(z_n)$ seems to converge towards
$$0.97605+0.87095 i.$$ Doesn't really help you, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen. May be not, but interesting for sure ! Funny are $z_2$ and $z_3$. Thanks :-)

Comment: $f(z)=z-\cosh(z)$ is an analytical function, the root or fixed point $z_*$ that you computed should be simple. The perturbation $f(z)=ϵz$ then has a solution $z_*+ϵv$ with $f'(z_*)v_1=z_*$ in first order. So $v_1=\frac{z_*}{1-\sinh(z_*)}=(1+\sinh(z_*))\frac{z_*}{2-z_*^2}$ should be sufficient to explain the digits for very small $ϵ$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=\zeta+\delta$ where $\zeta=\cosh(\zeta)$ and expand to get

\begin{align}\cosh(\zeta+\delta)&=(1-\epsilon)(\zeta+\delta)\\&=\zeta+\delta-\zeta\epsilon-\epsilon\delta\end{align}

Moving all of the $\delta$ to one side leaves us with

$$\cosh(\zeta+\delta)-\zeta-(1-\epsilon)\delta=-\zeta\epsilon$$

from which the LHS may be expanded and $\delta$ solved for via series reversion.

The first few terms can be found to be

$$\delta=\frac\zeta{1-\zeta'}\epsilon+\frac{\zeta^2+2-2\zeta'}{(1-\zeta')^3}\zeta\epsilon^2+\mathcal O(\epsilon^3)$$

where $\zeta'=\sinh(\zeta)=\sqrt{1+\zeta^2}$.